# How do I convert Unix timestamp to date in CockroachDB?

Tags: timestamp, unix-timestamp, cockroachdb

I've looked everywhere for this but can't find exactly what I need. I have a table that has a column in it containing the unix timestamp for the date of a transaction. In MySQL, I can convert this very easily but have been having a problem doing this in CockroachDB.

What I am looking for is simply to be able to query like the following would be done in MySQL:

```
SELECT
  DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_timestamp)),
  COUNT(id)
FROM 
  purchases
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the datatype of `transaction_timestamp`.

If it's a [`TIMESTAMP`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/timestamp.html), you can convert it to [`DATE`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/date.html) using one of:

- `SELECT transaction_timestamp :: DATE`
- `SELECT CAST(transaction_timestamp AS DATE)`

If it's just an [`INT`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/int.html) (or `DECIMAL` or `FLOAT`), you'll first need to cast it into a timestamp.

- `SELECT transaction_timestamp :: TIMESTAMP :: DATE`
- `SELECT CAST(CAST(transaction_timestamp AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATE)`

**DO NOT** cast directly from `INT/DECIMAL/FLOAT` to `DATE`, that interprets the value as the number of **days** since the Unix epoch.

The CRDB docs have more information about [casting](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/scalar-expressions.html#explicit-type-coercions) as well as casting rules for each data type ([`TIMESTAMP`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/timestamp.html#supported-casting-and-conversion) and [`DATE`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/date.html#supported-casting-and-conversion)).

Comment: This is great. I can get DATE and TIME working in separate columns. Any idea how to cast both date and time in the same column?